# JQuery Show Default Div Only

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

i will like to show the Div based on dropdownlist default selected value but can't works, it only able to show and hide when i change the selected value at drop down. I try use the Load function but it will show all Div. Anyone can guide me?

Below is my code:

```
<script>

    $('#dropDown').load(function () {
        $('.drop-down-show-hide').hide();
        $('#' + this.value).show();
    });

    $('#dropDown').change(function () {
        $('.drop-down-show-hide').hide();
        $('#' + this.value).show();
    });

</script>
```

View.cshtml:

```
<div id="Single_Line" class="drop-down-show-hide">
    <br />
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MaxChar)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MaxChar)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Qext_Text)
    </div>
</div>

<div id="Multiple_Line" class="drop-down-show-hide">
    <br />
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NumberOfLines)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NumberOfLines)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NumberOfLines)
    </div>
</div>
```

Dropdown List:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Question_Type, new SelectList(
                          new List<Object>{

                               new { value ="Single Line" , text = "Single_Line" },
                               new { value ="Multiple Line" , text = "Multiple_Line" },                         
                            },
                          "text",
                          "value",
                      0), new { @id = "dropDown" })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use bellow code  . add `$('#Single_Line').show();` in `$(document).ready()` function.

```
 <script>

  // Add this line of code if you want to show dive after DOM load. 
  $(window).load(function(){

     $('.drop-down-show-hide').hide();
     $('#'+$('#dropDown').val()).show(); 

   });

 </script>
```

Second Option

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

   $('.drop-down-show-hide').hide();
   $('#'+$('#dropDown').val()).show(); 

   $('#dropDown').load(function() {
      $('.drop-down-show-hide').hide();
      $('#' + this.value).show();
    });

     $('#dropDown').change(function() {
      $('.drop-down-show-hide').hide();
      $('#' + this.value).show();
    });       
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi .OK I will update my answer once reach office .. M on the way to office :)

Comment: @Edward.K i have updated my answer . please check . also i show drop down value is  new { value ="Single Line" , text = "Single_Line" },
                               new { value ="Multiple Line" , text = "Multiple_Line" },   without  `_`?

Comment: appreciate your help, and Thanks alot it works! Was marked your answer :)

Comment: by the way, i use the 1st option. Fast and clean *thumbs up*

Comment: yes it will call once all data load in window. it will not call before your dowpdown loads value.